# Insert apostrophe in sybase insert script

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq, sybase-asa, sybase-rs

There is a single quote in insert script. Like 'JOHN'S' , Is there any other way to insert it except using  Concat and two times single quote in Sybase.
Like 'JOHN''S'.

As I am able to handle it in oracle like q'(JOHN'S)'. Is there any function to handle this in sybase.

Comment: IIRC, you can use double quotes to delimit strings: `"JOHN'S"`

Comment: Insert Into table1 (DESC) Select "JOHN'S" as DESC from Table2----- Not working

Comment: Any way to replace in sql like 'JOHN'S'  to 'JOHN''S'.(This is two single quote not double quote)

Comment: use replace() or str_replace() --depending on which type of Sybase database you have--  t replace one quote by two.